# Swift extension type constraints for generic class where generic type is yet another generic type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions, type-constraints

I'm trying to wrap my head around generic type constraints in Swift. Here is my starting point:

```
class Promise<T> {
    func resolve(_ block:@escaping (T) ->Void) {}
    func fulfill(_ result:T) {}
}
```

A Promise is just that, something that can be fulfilled in the future. This becomes very useful when it is used with Swift's `Result` type when handing results back from a background queue to the main queue:

```
let promise = Promise<Result<String, Error>>()
promise.fulfill(.success("Hello"))
promise.fulfill(.failure(NSError()))
```

Now I would like to add an extension to all Promise instances that use `Result` to add these helper methods:

```
extension Promise where T == Result<X, Error> {
                                    ⬆︎ Here's the problem ⚡️
    func failure(_ error:Error) {
        fulfill(.failure(error))
    }

    func success(_ result:X) {
        fulfill(.success(result))
    }
}

// Shorter:
let promise = Promise<Result<String, Error>>()
promise.success("Hello")
promise.failure(NSError())
```

Only problem is that the above code does not compile, because `X` is not defined. What I want to express is this:

Extend `Promise` when its generic type `T` is of type `Result<X,Z>` where `X` can be anything and `Z` must be of type `Error` → `Result<*, Error>`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is possible, it's just that the syntax is slightly verbose. You can't put the `where` constraint on the extension. You have to put it on each method.

```
extension Promise {

    func failure<U>(_ error: Error) where T == Result<U, Error> {
        fulfill(.failure(error))
    }

    func success<U>(_ result: U) where T == Result<U, Error> {
        fulfill(.success(result))
    }
}
```

You can also do it with a protocol, but for enums I find this very klunky, because enum cases can't be treated as conforming methods.

```
protocol ResultType {
    associatedtype Success
    associatedtype Failure: Error
    static func makeFailure(_: Failure) -> Self
    static func makeSuccess(_: Success) -> Self
}

extension Result: ResultType {
    static func makeFailure(_ failure: Failure) -> Result<Success, Failure> { .failure(failure)  }
    static func makeSuccess(_ success: Success) -> Result<Success, Failure> { .success(success) }
}

extension Promise where T: ResultType {
    func failure(_ error: T.Failure) {
        fulfill(T.makeFailure(error))
    }

    func success(_ result: T.Success) {
        fulfill(T.makeSuccess(result))
    }
}
```